# User.IsInRole returning false

Tags: asp.net, .net, security

My ASP.NET app is using windows authentication.  If I run the following code:

```
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;

foreach (IdentityReference r in wi.Groups)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(r.Translate (typeof (NTAccount)).Value);
}

if (User.IsInRole ("Everyone"))
    Label1.Text = "Is in role";
```

The listbox will contain the name of every group the user belongs to.  If I then call `User.IsInRole`, and pass in the name of any of those groups, I always get a false.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: I really appreciate this troubleshooting code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to see your web.config.  How are roles handled?  Is the role manager even enabled?

**EDIT:**
You need to use this format:

```
User.IsInRole(@"DOMAINNAME\rolename")
```

You are leaving off the domain name.  If that still doesn't work, make sure you've got your role provider set in web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
```

This information comes straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx).  Look at the "Checking Role Membership in Code" section.  It's all there.

Comment: I'm betting that this is it.  The identity is there, sure, but membership and roles are two very different things.

Comment: If groups and roles are two different things, how would I enumerate all roles a user belongs to?

Comment: System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser().  ASP.NET *can* use Windows groups as Roles, but that's not required or enabled by default; it entirely depends on your web.config.

Comment: Can you show me how to modify my web.config file to allow asp.net to treat windows groups as roles?

Thanks

Comment: Now that I look at your code again, it's possible you're just not checking the role properly.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan.  Adding defaultProvider to the roleManager did the trick.